# Abort HTTP request without closing the connection in Netty

Tags: http, netty

How can I abort the HTTP Request and not close the connection while implementing a netty HTTP client?

At the moment I am using `NioSocketChannel` and I am confused if [doClose](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/socket/nio/NioSocketChannel.html#doClose--) is the only option.

Is there a more generic way of canceling the request, that can work with any kind of socket channel, eg KQueue?

Answer (score 1):

Netty's `ChannelFuture` extends the netty `Future` which provides a `cancel` method: https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-

I'm pretty sure that's what you're looking for.

`doClose` closes the channel where a channel is described as *"A nexus to a network socket or a component which is capable of I/O operations such as read, write, connect, and bind."* So that would close the connection, as you're seeing. It doesn't look like that's going to help you.